# Express + Typescript: Property 'body' does not exist on type 'Request'

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, backend, body-parser

I got the following code:

```
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import express, { Router } from 'express';

const router: Router = express.Router();

router.use(bodyParser.json());

router.post('/api/users/signup', (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
    const {email, password} = req.body;

    if (!email || typeof email !== 'string') {
        res.status(400).send('Provide a valid email');
    }
});

export {router as signUpRouter};
```

Here, the `req.body` is showing the error of

> Property 'body' does not exist on type 'Request'

And I have downloaded following libraries:

```sh
npm install express @types/express body-parser @types/body-parser typescript ts-node-dev
```

Comment: i have also init typescript using `tsc --init`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the new node version( **v14+**) and **Express** `v4.16.0 onwards`, replace

`router.use(bodyParser.json());`

with

`router.use(express.json());`

Comment: can you tell the version number of node, as i got latest still `your suggestion has no .json() method in express showing`

Comment: I got it thanks for your help. Actually i downloaded this node package outside the folder. LOL silly Mistake :)

Comment: I have `node 16.3.0` and `express 4.17.2` and still am getting `Property 'body' does not exist on type 'Request'.` when I try and access it in the controller file.